# Problems connecting google charts to a javaScript calculator in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-visualization

I've been working on designing a calculator in JavaScript that feeds data to a google column chart. The basic idea is that the result of the calculation determines the height of one of the columns in the chart. It works the way it should in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer, where the chart simply does not show up at all. I've tried to fix this problem for two days now, but with no success, so if anybody out there could give a n00b a helping hand, that would be very appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function CalculateSum(Atext, Btext, Ctext, form)
{
var A = parseFloat(Atext);
var B = parseFloat(Btext);
var C = parseFloat(Ctext);
form.Answer.value = A * B * C;
}
function ClearForm(form)
{
form.input_A.value = "";
form.input_B.value = "";
form.input_C.value = "";
form.Answer.value = "";
}
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work', Number(a.value)],
          ['Eat', 2],
          ['Commute', 2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep', 7]
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">
<P>Population (billions): <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_A" SIZE=10></P>
<P>Affluence (PPP US$): <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_B" SIZE=10></P>
<p>Technology (tonnes per $): <Input TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_C" SIZE=10></p>
<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" name="AddButton" onClick="CalculateSum(this.form.input_A.value, this.form.input_B.value, this.form.input_C.value, this.form); drawVisualization()"></P>
<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Clear Fields" name="ClearButton" onClick="ClearForm(this.form)"></P>
<P>Impact (billions of tonnes): <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=12 id="a"></P>
</FORM>
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`['Work', Number(a.value)],` should be `['Work', Number(document.getElementById("a").value)],`

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">
<P>Population (billions): <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_A" SIZE=10></P>
<P>Affluence (PPP US$): <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_B" SIZE=10></P>
<p>Technology (tonnes per $): <Input TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_C" SIZE=10></p>
<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" name="AddButton" onClick="CalculateSum(this.form.input_A.value, this.form.input_B.value, this.form.input_C.value, this.form); drawVisualization()"></P>
<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Clear Fields" name="ClearButton" onClick="ClearForm(this.form)"></P>
<P>Impact (billions of tonnes): <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Answer" SIZE=12 id="a"></P>
</FORM>
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
function CalculateSum(Atext, Btext, Ctext, form)
{
var A = parseFloat(Atext);
var B = parseFloat(Btext);
var C = parseFloat(Ctext);
form.Answer.value = A * B * C;
}
function ClearForm(form)
{
form.input_A.value = "";
form.input_B.value = "";
form.input_C.value = "";
form.Answer.value = "";
}
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work', Number(document.getElementById("a").value)],
          ['Eat', 2],
          ['Commute', 2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep', 7]
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```